# upstart-socket-bridge and python3 example

Tags: upstart, python3

I'm trying to get upstart-socket-bridge to pass the socket to a Python3 application.

Are there any working examples of u-s-b using Python 2 or 3?

This example is a test setup only.
u-s-b launches the Python3 application, but the file descriptor from Upstart seems invalid.

```
# Edited to remove lots of debug lines
import os, traceback, socket
fd = os.environ["UPSTART_FDS"]

# Log the socket connection activity
with open("/tmp/socket-test-outfile", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("debug: fd={}\n".format(fd))
    try:
        s = socket.fromfd(fd, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.listen(1)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        outfile.write("{}\n".format(conn.recv(1024).decode('UTF-8')))
    except:
        outfile.write("s error: {}\n".format(traceback.print_exc()))
    outfile.close()
```

fd = 10 on all attempts so far. 
But that fd doesn't produce a useful socket that I can accept() and read().
The error output is None

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.fromfd(10, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/socket.py", line 219, in fromfd
    nfd = dup(fd)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

How can I get upstart-socket-bridge working with Python?

Comment: Answer: There are a couple problems here. The specific error is the fd needs to be int(fd). Other fatal problems are addressed in a longer writeup: http://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/upstart-socket-bridge.html

Comment: Why not writing the content of the blog (**not just the link**) in the answer section below?

Comment: Because it's really, really long. Bad assumptions, misunderstanding about how u-d-s works with sockets, etc.

Comment: Ok, just copy the relevant parts and put it here.

Comment: See the first comment. The shown error is resolved by a cast to int. I voted to close my own question here: Neither the question nor answer will help anybody else without a lot more context. Now that I understand more, I don't think it's a suitable or useful question/answer for the AskUbuntu format.